# How to access a variable that is out of scope?

Tags: c++, pointers

```
class foo{
    vector<foo*>* queue;
    vector<int> pos;
    foo(vector<foo*>* queue, vector<int> pos){
        this->queue=queue;
        this->pos=pos;
    }
public:
    foo(vector<foo*>* queue){
        this->queue=queue;
    }
    void init(){
        vector<int> posNew = pos;
        //Create Binary Tree Children of the state FOO
        posNew.push_back(/* An Additional Value*/)
        foo newFoo(queue, posNew);
        queue->push_back(&newFoo);
    }//Here the variables newFoo and posNew are out of scope so they are deleted even from the queue
}

class bar{
    vector<foo*> queue; //Assume that queue has a root node added to it.
    bar(){
        for(unsigned int i=0; i<queue.size();i++){
            queue[i]->init();// Somewhere along when the third element is calculated the value overflows since I assume the object are deleted
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to use BFS search with a queue to solve a problem. However I am not able to get the queue to work since the object child object I create are going out of scope. Any help of this would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**
In my actual code, I am having trouble since when the object goes out of scope it shows me these memory allocations.
[image]

This green part is where the root node is, the red part is where the expected data for the child nodes was supposed to be but its now deleted.

Comment: Why do you need `init()`? Move stuff it does to ctor (`foo(vector<state*>*)`).

Comment: In the constructor for `bar`, `queue` will be empty (i.e. there are no elements to iterate over).

Comment: @crashmstr we are assuming that the queue allready has a root node added to it mually for the binary tree.

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus ctor?

Comment: @shadoweye14 constructor

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus My bad. Forgot to change the code a bit. The queue is of type `vector<foo*>`

Comment: @shadoweye14 so in the constructor you show, somewhere after `queue` is initialized, you have some magic hidden code that adds to it? Post your *actual* code, not some imaginary thought experiment.

Comment: Sorry, but I thought posting an MCVE was the way to be done, since I didn't think you'd want to read over 250 lines of code. In any case, http://pastebin.com/w9XtTKkz that's the code I have so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The variable `queue` is a vector of `foo` pointers, not `foo` objects. But in `init()`, you are declaring `newFoo` as a `foo` object and pushing it in the queue. `newFoo` is a local variable of function `init()`, so when the function finishes execution, `newFoo` is lost.

You can declare `newFoo` as a pointer and allocate memory for it, like

```
foo *newFoo = new foo(queue, posNew);
```

and push `newFoo` in your queue.

Comment: Ahh my bad about that, I was actually doing it using the `&newFoo` operator instead of initially declaring it like a pointer. Does that work the same?

Comment: Nope. `newFoo` is still a local variable, and it will be lost after `init()` finishes. So `&newFoo` would point to some garbage value.

Comment: Ahh! However in the real code since I have multiple parameters for `foo*` its giving me this error on an `unsigned int` parameter.. Any guesses why? http://puu.sh/lI8ia/8d6f91f18a.png

Comment: @shadoweye14 It does not work the same.  The local pointer variable simply points to a memory location rather than being the object itself.  A good way to imagine this is that you have a house and a sign that points to the house.  When you destroy the house the house is gone.  When you destroy the sign pointing at the house the house is still there.  The way you did it in your code was to create a house, build a sign pointing to the house, then destroy the house.  The sign is still pointing at where the house used to be.

Comment: However as I mentioned if I do that in my real code I am getting the error like `a value of type "unsigned int" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "foo *"`

Comment: @soulsabr great analogy.
@shadoweye14 I think the first parameter of the constructor is declared as of type `foo *`, but you're providing an `unsigned int`. That's why the error. Can't tell more without seeing the code.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/w9XtTKkz That's the code line 172. I would really appreciate the help. Been banging my head over this for lord knows how long.

Comment: Rewrite the line as `state *childNode = new state(n, (queens + 1), parent, root, n_QList, queue);`, it should work fine.

Comment: :O You are god! Thanks a lot, now all I need to do is fix the logic of my code.

Answer (score 1):

There are two meanings of "out of scope":

1. Through a function call, you jump to part of the program outside the lexical scope of the identifier.  The object exists, but cannot be directly named.  Indirection (pointer or reference) may be able to reach the object.
2. For objects with automatic lifetime, when the end of the scope is reached, the object is destroyed.  There is no way to access the object after this point, because it no longer exists.

As 0605002 suggests, one way to avoid case #2 is to use lifetime other than automatic -- his answer shows an example of dynamic lifetime, but static lifetime is also possible, and data members also have lifetime that outlasts a single function call.

For your queue, dynamic lifetime managed by a smart pointer (`std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`) would be a good choice.